# Weird Protruding Vertices while in Sculpt Mode

Tags: modeling, vertices, error, sculpt-mode

I'm doing an axe but when I get into sculpting, the vertex from the edge get crazy. I don't know if it's because of the original mesh or because I did something on sculp mode. No matters how many times I smoot that part and they go to their place that they pop again to where they where after a few seconds. Any help would be great.[image][image][image]

Comment: Did you try to do a merge by distance bevor the sculpting, and applied mirror modifier?

Comment: yes, i did that and by doing that i created tris and i think my model collapsed because of that. I'm redoing it now without tris and it seems to be working well

Comment: Perfect, could you add this as an answer so others know to avoid tris in this situation?